# Remove persistent notification from list of notifications (Notifications API)

Tags: google-chrome, push-notification, notifications, web-push

When calling `self.registration.getNotifications({ tag: tag })` from a service worker, the returned array always contains old notifications which have been replaced. For example:

```
showNotification('A', { tag: 'abc' }) // Displays the first notification
getNotifications({ tag: 'abc' }) // Returns [ NotificationA ]
showNotification('B', { tag: 'abc' }) // Replaces the previous notification
getNotifications({ tag: 'abc' }) // Returns [ NotificationB, NotificationA ]
showNotification('C', { tag: 'abc' }) // Replaces the previous notification
getNotifications({ tag: 'abc' }) // Returns [ NotificationC, NotificationB, NotificationA ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though Notification API specs are clear about the [steps for replacing a notification](https://notifications.spec.whatwg.org/#replacing-a-notification):

> 1. ...
> 2. Replace old with new, in the same position, in the list of notifications.
> 3. ...

The implementation keeps the old notification in the list until the `.close()` is explicitly called from the code or until the user clicks the [x] button on the notification itself, implicitly running `.close()`.